# Cast class to unknown subclass by name?

Tags: java, casting

First off, sorry for the confusing title. It even confuses me so I don't wat to think about a better title any more.

Though, let's get to my problem. I have a class `Classss`. That class has some variables and a `doSomething()` void.

Now, that class has lots of classes `extending` that class, with different values of the variables and  a different `doSomething` void. Now, I have the name of a class, something like "com.cool.cool.Cool".

So, I know that that class is a subclass of `Classss` and I have the name. Is there any way I can load that class by its name and be able to treat it as a `Classss`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share your code? It's pretty hard to follow this only with the description.

Comment: Are you talking about polymorphism, or reflection ?

Comment: Do you want something like, `Class<? extends Classss>` and then get an instance from that?

Comment: I think you are talking about Class.forName("com.cool.cool.Cool"), this will give you the instance of child class

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like this the classic case of polymorphism. Where you want to treat all subclasses the same way as the top class.

Basically, you can do this:

```
Classs c1 = new Cool(); // This works
Classs c2 = new SubClass(); // This works

c1.doSomething(); // Will call the Cool.doSomething() method;
c2.doSomething(); // Will call the SubClass.doSomething method;
```

You can also use `List<Classs>` and put subClass object in it...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
static Bar getSubclass(String name) throws Exception{

    Class<?> c = Class.forName(name);
    Constructor<?> con = c.getConstructor();
    return (Bar)con.newInstance();

}
```

This should work, provided `name` is the fully qualified name of a class that extends Bar and has a no-arg constructor.

```
class Bar{}
class Foo extends Bar{ public Foo(){} }
```

This is pretty prone to breaking.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question mentions “load that class by its name” I assume you are using the Class.forName method.

java.lang.Class has an [asSubclass](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass(java.lang.Class)) method which I believe will do what you want:

```
Class<?> loadedClass = Class.forName(name);
Class<? extends Classss> type = loadedClass.asSubclass(Classss.class);
```

Your example name of “Classss” makes the above rather confusing, so I’ll repeat it using the name ExampleService:

```
Class<?> loadedClass = Class.forName(name);
Class<? extends ExampleService> type = loadedClass.asSubclass(ExampleService.class);
```

Alternatively, you may want to make use of [the service provider facility](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html), which is designed to dynamically search for “plugins,” that is, foreign implementations of an interface or abstract class:

```
for (ExampleService service : ServiceLoader.load(ExampleService.class)) {
    System.out.println("Found subclass: " + service.getClass());
}
```